# Automatically trigger an Enter key press after write text into a search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm writing some code to trigger <kbd>Enter</kbd> right after I put the text I got from an img alt into a search box.

I'm working with jQuery DataTables. But I want to create my own filter outside the table. I want to have icons to click to filter the table.

Because jQuery DataTables can pull out result if you put text in the search box, I figured that if I can get the text from the img alt and write the text into the search box, it will do the filtering.

But it didn't work, it needs to be entered.

So how can I trigger the <kbd>Enter</kbd>? Or it's just a completely wrong idea to do this way?

```
 <img alt="High School" src="../../slack.png" class="icon"></img>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('.icon').on('click', function(){
       var text = $('.icon').first().attr("alt");
      $('.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').val(text);
      $('input').submit();
      })
    })
   </script>
```

Update on the post. It's solved and it can work with dataTable.
Here's the code:

```
<img alt="High School" src="../../slack.png" class="icon" id="High School"></img>
    <img alt="Elementary School" src="../../ai.png" class="icon" id="Elementary School"></img>
<script>
var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13;
$(function(){
  $('.icon').on('click', function(){
   var text = $(this).attr("id");
  $('.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').val(text);
  $('input').trigger('keyup',e);

  })
})
```

Comment: Does that `input` have an event listener defined? You can only trigger the event listeners you define, not native functionality

Comment: @tymeJV oh I thought the input means the same thing as .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="functions.php">
            <input type="text" name="user_input" id="search">
            <button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your javascript code. Add this:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var search_box = $("input#search");
    search_box.on("input blur change", function(){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my zero knowledge about php. And the search box is built in with dataTable, I'm not sure if I could just give it an ID. attr("id", "search")?

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to have icons to click to filter the table"

I think you overcomplicate this task. If you have a dataTable created by

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

then all you have to do, if you want to search by the `alt` attribute when clicking on an `<img>` with the class `.icon` :

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
    table.search(this.alt).draw();
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/twpe2cpz/**

Comment: it worked really well in the fiddle but when i tried it, it told me that search is not a function...

Comment: @Candtiimer, this is because 1) you have initialized with `dataTable()` not `DataTable()`, _or_, most likely 2) you initialise the dataTable inside a function, like a `$(document).ready()`, where you set the variable as `var table=`, and thus are `table` not a variable visible to the outer scope from where you declare `click()`. Sry for the long delay.